# Changing lineJoin of a SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a SKShapeNode and want to change the junction type for my stroked line from kCGLineJoinBevel (default) to kCGLineJoinMiter, but I don't know how.

```
let corner = SKShapeNode()
let cornerPath = drawShape()
corner.path = cornerPath.CGPath
corner.lineWidth = rectyLineWidth
corner.fillColor = SKColor.clearColor()
corner.strokeColor = fillColor
corner.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
```

The last line throws this error, because it is not a CAShapeLayer

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'CGLineJoin'

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer :)

```
corner.lineJoin = CGLineJoin.Miter
```